# What are the possible causes of "Abnormal Program Termination" error in a C Program?

Tags: c, algorithm

The following code is to find the number of Islands by considering 1 as island and 0 as water in a 2d array. Adjacent 1s belong to the same island and the island can be of any shape.It means
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
should give the number of islands as 1.This code runs and prints something for a 2 x 2 matrix, but shows "Abnormal termination error" for any higher order matrix.Whats wrong with the code and how to overcome the error? I just tried to make adjacent element zero recursively but ended up in this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int a[10][10],m,n;
int islands=0;

void MakeZero(int,int);

void main()
{
   int i,j;
   clrscr();
   printf("Enter the number of rows and columns :");
   scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
   printf("Enter the matrix of 0s and 1s\n");
   for(i=0;i<m;i++){
      for(j=0;j<n;j++){
         scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
      }
   }
   printf("Input Matrix is :\n");
   for(i=0;i<m;i++){
      for(j=0;j<n;j++){
         printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
      }printf("\n");
   }

   printf("The Number of Islands is :\n");
   for(i=0;i<m;i++){
      for(j=0;j<n;j++){
         if(a[i][j])
         {islands++;
            MakeZero(i,j); }
      }
   }
   printf("%d",islands);
   getch();
}

void MakeZero(int i,int j)
{
   if(i>m-1||j>n-1)
      return;
   else if(i==0&&j==0)
   {
      if(a[i][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i,j+1);
      if(a[i+1][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j+1);
      if(a[i+1][j]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j);
      a[i][j+1]=a[i+1][j+1]=a[i+1][j]=0;
   }
   else if(i==m-1&&j==0)
   {
      if(a[i-1][j]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j);
      if(a[i][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i,j+1);
      if(a[i-1][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j+1);
      a[i-1][j]=a[i][j+1]=a[i-1][j+1]=0;
   }
   else if(i==0&&j==n-1)
   {
      if(a[i][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i,j-1);
      if(a[i+1][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j-1);
      if(a[i+1][j]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j);
      a[i][j-1]=a[i+1][j-1]=a[i+1][j]=0;
   }
   else if(i==m-1&&j==n-1)
   {
      if(a[i][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i,j-1);
      if(a[i-1][j]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j);
      if(a[i-1][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j-1);
      a[i][j-1]=a[i-1][j]=a[i-1][j-1]=0;
   }
   else if(i==0&&(j>0&&j<n-1))
   {
      if(a[i][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i,j-1);
      if(a[i][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i,j+1);
      if(a[i+1][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j-1);
      if(a[i+1][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j+1);
      if(a[i+1][j]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j);
      a[i][j-1]=a[i][j+1]=a[i+1][j-1]=a[i+1][j+1]=a[i+1][j]=0;
   }
   else if(i==m-1&&(j>0&&j<n-1))
   {
      if(a[i][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i,j-1);
      if(a[i][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i,j+1);
      if(a[i-1][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j-1);
      if(a[i-1][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j+1);
      if(a[i-1][j]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j);
      a[i][j-1]=a[i][j+1]=a[i-1][j-1]=a[i-1][j+1]=a[i-1][j]=0;
   }
   else if(j==0&&(i>0&&i<m-1))
   {
      if(a[i-1][j]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j);
      if(a[i+1][j]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j);
      if(a[i-1][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j+1);
      if(a[i+1][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j+1);
      if(a[i][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i,j+1);
      a[i-1][j]=a[i+1][j]=a[i-1][j+1]=a[i+1][j+1]=a[i][j+1]=0;
   }
   else if(j==n-1&&(i>0&&i<m-1))
   {
      if(a[i-1][j]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j);
      if(a[i+1][j]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j);
      if(a[i-1][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j-1);
      if(a[i+1][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j-1);
      if(a[i][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i,j-1);
      a[i-1][j]=a[i+1][j]=a[i-1][j-1]=a[i+1][j-1]=a[i][j-1]=0;
   }
   else
   {
      if(a[i-1][j]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j);
      if(a[i+1][j]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j);
      if(a[i-1][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j-1);
      if(a[i+1][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j-1);
      if(a[i][j-1]==1)MakeZero(i,j-1);
      if(a[i][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i,j+1);
      if(a[i-1][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i-1,j+1);
      if(a[i+1][j+1]==1)MakeZero(i+1,j+1);
      a[i-1][j]=a[i+1][j]=a[i-1][j-1]=a[i+1][j-1]=a[i][j-1]=a[i][j+1]=a[i-1][j+1]=a[i+1][j+1]=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it in a debugger?

Comment: Think of whan you mark the squares as zero. Your approach is like going into the labyrith and saying: I'll drop the breadcrumbs on my way back.

Comment: Stack Overflow is happening.

Comment: 'a[i-1][j]=a[i+1][j]=a[i-1][j-1]=a[i+1][j-1]=a[i][j-1]=a[i][j+1]=a[i-1][j+1]=a[i+1][j+1]=0' - sure, I'm falling over myself to debug that for you :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **M Oehm** already said the problem is the time you mark a square as zero (or let's say "visited").

Your function `MakeZero` calls itself whenever it finds a square with a one in at least one of the neighbouring squares. Since you mark the square as `0` **after** calling `MakeZero` this results in a stack overflow whenever there are two neighbouring squares containing a `1` within your matrix. Since the first `MakeZero` finds a neighbouring `1`and calls `MakeZero` which also finds a neighbouring `1`and calls `MakeZero` again ... (you can see this if you look at the call stack from within the debugger).

Another thing about your `MakeZero` implementation: You are explicitly  handling all special cases within `MakeZero` which make the code quite lengthy and harder to understand. I recommend to modify the function to only check if the input values are valid and the square is a one. If so set the value to zero and call `MakeZero` for all neighbouring squares (regardless of the current location within the matrix). An implementation would look like the following:

```
void MakeZero(int i, int j)
{
   int x, y;

   if ((i >= 0) && (i < m) &&   /* i index valid? */
       (j >= 0) && (j < n) &&   /* j index valid? */
       (a[i][j] == 1))          /* square is an island? */
   {
      a[i][j] = 0;   /* remove 1 from matrix !!! */

      /* iterate all surrounding squares */
      for (x = (i - 1); x <= (i + 1); x++)
      {
         for (y = (j - 1); y <= (j + 1); y++)
         {
            MakeZero(x, y);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program provokes a stack overflow because your recursive function `MakeZero()` never reaches the base case. Using the same input example that you provide and just adding a `printf ("%d %d\n", i, j);` in the last `else` condition of `Makezero`, the program will output `1 1` indefinitely and you will never reach the condition `(i > m-1 || j > n-1)` that stops the program, since the values of `m-1` and `n-1` are `2` and `i = 1` and `j = 1` ad eternum.

Suggestion: try to find out what's going on when at least one of the values in the matrix `a` is `0`, because the stack overflow seems to be happening only in this case.